# Laravel: Get time between two timestamps in diffForHumans format (Carbon)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the time between two dates in `diffForHumans` format, can anyone help me out to why its throwing this error?

Code:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($clientLogin->exit_timestamp)->diffForHumans($clientLogin->enter_timestamp) }}
```

Error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::encrypt() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, instance of Illuminate\View\View given

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Define your datetime fields as dates so Laravel can treat then already as a carbon instance, so you can do something like this:

```
$clientLogin->exit_timestamp->subDays($clientLogin->enter_timestamp)->diffForHumans();
```